# не подключается устройство (через браузер по http) по локальной сети к live-server

Tags: linux, xubuntu

Не могу зайти с других устройств по локальной сети на сервер live-server, в консоли пишу такую команду - live-server --host=192.168.1.218, на самой машине через браузер подключается к серверу по адресу 192.168.1.218:8080, но когда пытаюсь по этожему адресу зайти через android-устройство - не подключается, в браузере пишет - что страница не доступна. live-server стоит на Xubuntu - машине. Локальная сеть подключена через роутер D-Link

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверить, не блокирует ли соединения фаервол на Xubuntu. Для надежности можно сбросить правила "**iptables -F**"
2. Удостовериться, что Xubuntu соединен с локальной сетью именно той сетевой картой, которая имеет IP 192.168.1.218
3. Попробовать поставить на андроид устройство сетевой сканер, наподобие [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing) и посмотреть: доступен ли хост 192.168.1.218 по сети, открыт ли на нем порт 8080
4. Если Xubuntu подключается к сети проводом, а андроид устройство - по wi-fi: проверить настройки роутера на наличие настроенных [VLAN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLAN) или нестандартных правил фаервола, маршрутизации или любых других настроек, которые могут помешать связи между физическими сетями

Comment: сделал iptables -F - всё также, установил на android -  fing, сделал сканирование, написало что на 192.168.1.218 запущена только одна служба с портом 80, сделал ping. ping до Xubunu(192.168.1.218) не идёт. Xubuntu подключён по кабелю, android по wi-fi. На роутере файрвол отключен, остальные настройки VLAN, правила маршрутизации - я в этом не розбираюсь, модель роутера -и D-link DSL-264OU. Забыл сказать что на Xubuntu установлен VPN, может при установки vpn, поменялись какие то настройки?

Comment: 1 -  на роутере может быть настройка - изолировать клиентов - проверьте её и отключите. 2 - аналогичная настройка может быть и в  vpn - нужно смотреть настройки именно вашего vpn клиента/сервера.

Comment: На роутере нашёл только опцию - статические клиенты и динамические клиенты, Xubuntu - находится в разделе статических клиентов, а wi-fi сеть в резделе динамических устройств, там есть переключатель вкл./выкл dhcp-сервер для этих разделов, при том не понятно в каком состянию он включён в акоком выключен, там графический интерфейс. Но я смог решить проблему, у меня на android тоже стоит vpn, я его отключил, и смог подключиться на адрес 192.168.1.218:8080

Comment: Я кажется понял в чём была проблема, т.к. у меня на android постоянно включён vpn, поэтому между сетевым интерфейсом android и сервером vpn установлен тунель(соединение точка-точка между vpn  клиентом и сервером) и когда я делаю запрос на 192.168.1.218, то запрос идёт по тунелю к vpn-серверу, и конечно там такого адреса нет.